# Last time logged in the site

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have this lines:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe');
$timer = $row['lastlogin'];
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

`$timer` get some date from database, that is before today.
`$today` is the current time in my country.

How I can get how much time have been since `$timer` to `$today`?

Comment: Show us the results of `var_dump($timer)`.  Is it a unix timestamp? A mysql datetime? Something else?

Comment: What's the column type of `lastlogin` - `int`, `date`, `time`, `datetime`? Or sth else?

Comment: Convert both to UNIX timestamp, $timediff = $today - $timer; and take a look at the helper functions here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Answer (score 0):

As @Alexander said, convert to timestamp, make the diff and format like you want.

[gettimestamp()](http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.gettimestamp.php) and [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) may help you